# ERROR: could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp32058.285": No space left on device SQL state: 53100

Tags: postgresql

can i please get some assistance re: why i am receiving this error and how can i fix this?

ERROR:  could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp32058.285": No space left on device SQL state: 53100

i have 110 GB free space on my local disk and i still got this error that says " no space left on device SQL State: 53100".

I got this error on PGAdmin 4 version 6.9. PostgreSQL 13.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit

also i got the above error when i run the following query

```
with sh as
(select event_site, payor, name_policy, program, event_id from cart_item_funder_policy_worker where event_Status like 'Show%' 
    and event_time between '2022-04-01' and '2022-09-30'),
ns as
(select payor, name_policy, program, event_id from cart_item_funder_policy_worker where event_Status like 'No Show%' 
    and event_time between '2022-04-01' and '2022-09-30')
select crt.payor, count(distinct sh.event_id) as show_, count(distinct ns.event_id) as noshow_
from cart_item_funder_policy_worker as crt
left join sh on sh.payor = crt.payor
left join ns on crt.payor = ns.payor
group by crt.payor;
```

in above query i am only getting crt.payor and 2 column of values. this simple query took 11 minutes to run and this is not even a complete query. i further need to group these by event_site, name_policy, program.

follwing is the table i have

| event_site | payor | name_policy | program | event_id | event_status | evnt_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| canada | ministry | new_policy | gender-based | 10202 | show | 14-12-2022 |
| usa | community | old_policy | preferred | r303 | No show | 13-9-2022 |
| India | ministry | new_policy | gender-based | 144202 | No show | 31-10-2022 |
| Italy | local | OCH | open | 14822 | show | 1-10-2022 |

i want to see distinct count of show and no show event_id
grouped by svent_site, payor, name_policy

my query gives me what i want if i only run it for show events. when i run it for show and no show it give me that above error and takes 11 minutes to run.

any help is appreciated.

below is the query plan

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y-NunNAGi1pZ5S46ieY5GkYgXnmKmSaE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i would guess that the tablespace is on qa different drive or has a quota

Comment: hi @ nbk my apologies i did not understand your comment.

Comment: @nbk Not at all. He ran out of space in the data directory.

Comment: Please edit the question and add your PostgreSQL version and the result of plain `EXPLAIN` for the query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe postgres saves the temp file in the tablespace as far as i can understand it and not in the default Temp of the system, besides of the temp file there are more files like error log and other log files created, but the user claims that he has 110 Gigabyte free space. the tabole is not normalized so could be much smaller. your suggestion for an EXPLAIN is very good and will show some helpful hints, but the basic design seems a problem that should be soved before

Comment: @RahulDevvasisht follow Laurenz Advice and run a EXPLAIN your_query, basically i said, that when you run your query you will lose some of your 110 Gigbyte depending on the configuration see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/storage-file-layout.html

Comment: @nbk i am trying to share the query plan here but it does not let me. how can i attach it as a file.

Comment: @nbk and @ laurenz Albe here is the query plan https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y-NunNAGi1pZ5S46ieY5GkYgXnmKmSaE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your plan is exorbitantly complicated.  Apparently the tables you are querying are really  complicated views and not just simple tables.  Just based on the info we have, there is no way to say it can't be just a straightforward case of needing more temp space then you have.  You say you have 110GB free space.  OK, but what if you need 130GB?

Comment: @jjanes thanks i will use direct tables and not use views then.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the 110 GB of free space are not sufficient. To resolve this issue just free up more disk space. You can monitor the disk space usage in real-time by running `watch -d -n 3 'df -h'` in another shell (you'll notice that postgres uses free space aggressively).

postgres can consume a considerable amount of space when handling large result sets. For example, I recently had the same issue when joining two tables (one has 17 GB and the other one 1 GB). In this case, postgres allocated over 24 GB right at the beginning of the query execution and I had only 21GB free - I just increased the VM disk size and it worked. You can use the view created on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/turicas/afcde268b9616cfb6b9d69a7831d77ec) to check how much space your tables are taking.