# PG Client Error : could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/temp_file"

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres, node.js-fs

I am using node-postgres PG client on a node.js app to query data from the database and pass the results to an express.js response. This works perfectly fine. However, it takes a bit of time to get results and would rather create a cron-job to save the results in a file. The express api endpoint will pass this saved file as a response.

Doing this using `fs.writeFile` or `fs.createWriteStream` raises a `PG Client Error: error: could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp6554.0": No space left on device`

Code reproduction

```js
const { getData } = require("./pg_queries"); 
const fs = require("fs");
const cron = require("node-cron");

const pull_and_save = async () => {
 fs.writeFile(
    "data/results.json",
    JSON.stringify(await getData()),
    { flag: "w+" },
    (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );
}


cron.schedule("* */10 * * * *", function () {
  pull_and_save();
});
```

Searching around on the problem, the likely resolution would be to [free up more disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909092/error-could-not-write-to-file-base-pgsql-tmp-pgsql-tmp32058-285-no-space-lef#:%7E:text=To%20resolve%20this%20issue%20just,when%20handling%20large%20result%20sets.)

My question is why does the same Postgress query work with `express` and not `fs.writeFile` or `fs.createWriteStream`?

Code snippet for express endpoint example:

```js
const { getData } = require("./pg_queries"); 
const app = express();


app.get("/get-pg-data", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await getData();
  res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: The simple explanation for it working some time and not others is that there is more free space available some times, and not others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by effectively copying data from a PostgreSQL query result to a file using streaming.

Try this code;

```
const { getData } = require("./pg_queries");
const fs = require("fs");
const cron = require("node-cron");
const { Client } = require("pg");
const copyTo = require("pg-copy-streams").to;

const connectionString = "your-postgres-connection-string";
const client = new Client({ connectionString });

const pull_and_save = async () => {
  const query = getData(); // Assuming getData returns a query stream
  const stream = client.query(copyTo('COPY (' + query.text + ') TO STDOUT'));
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream("data/results.json");

  stream.pipe(fileStream);

  stream.on("end", () => {
    client.end();
    console.log("Data has been saved to data/results.json");
  });

  stream.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Error streaming data:", err);
    client.end();
  });
};

client.connect();

cron.schedule("* */10 * * * *", function () {
  pull_and_save();
});
```

It copies data from a PostgreSQL query result to a file called "data/results.json," while a cron job handles connections and errors. This approach works without using an excessive amount of RAM.

Hope it works :)